# ターミナルでデスクトップ上のディレクトリへ移動できない

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, cocoapods

大変お恥ずかしいのですがターミナルでディレクトリへ移動できない問題が生じております｡

Xcodeのファイル一式はデスクトップ上に保管しております[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下記のコマンドで移動を試みましたが`No such file or directory`と表示されてしまいます｡

```
Last login: Fri Oct 21 08:38:25 on ttys003
〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇-no-MacBook-Pro:~ 〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇$ cd/desktop/cocoatest
-bash: cd/desktop/cocoatest: No such file or directory
〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇-no-MacBook-Pro:~ 〇〇〇〇〇〇〇〇$ cd/Xcode/cocoatest
-bash: cd/Xcode/cocoatest: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

書き間違いでなければ、`cd`コマンドと移動先のディレクトリの間にはスペースが必要です。
スペースがないため、一つのコマンド（またはファイル）と認識されているので失敗しています。

また、`cocoatest`ディレクトリがデスクトップにあるなら下記のようになるのが正しいと思います。

```
cd ~/Desktop/cocoatest
```